# Sci-fi/horror anthology with a story about a boy who survives a crash and finds an alien who can cause pain with its mind

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have been looking for a specific science fiction/horror anthology book for years. I do not recall the cover art, the publisher, the title, or the author. I am only able to recall bits and pieces of different stories in the book.

The main one I remember is about a group of young boys in a space camp. They are in a rocket, when they suddenly crash onto an alien planet. All of the boys are killed except one. The one survivor stumbles upon a grotesque, translucent, talking alien head who has gray brain matter visible through his clear skull. The alien head is able to use its mind to cause pain to the boy, such as making him feel as though he is on fire. I don't recall the ending.

If I'm not mistaken, another story in the book is about a boy on vacation with his family. He gets angry with them, and runs away to an old movie theater. He sees a movie by himself, falls asleep in the theater, and wakes up years later in that same theater as an old man.

I'm not entirely certain, but I believe it may have been published sometime in the 80s and 90s. I believe it was a paperback, and it was published in English in the United States. It was given to me by a friend who has since passed away, and she picked it up from some used book store and had it for a while before it came to me at the age of 10 in 2002. I've been advised to check out Ray Bradbury and Orson Scott Card, but haven't had any luck yet.